# Flink cluster deployed with "Fencing token not set exception"

Tags: java, apache-flink

What does mean this exception?

I am trying to deploy flink cluster(v.1.5.2) with 3 nodes in HA mode (zookeeper).

I have following flink-conf.yaml settings:

```
high-availability: zookeeper    
high-availability.storageDir: /flink/ha    
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: {node1_ip}:2181,{node2_ip}:2181,{node3_ip}:2181    
high-availability.jobmanager.port: 50010    
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink    
high-availability.zookeeper.path.namespace: /default_ns
```

Zookeeper cluster is running.
After start-cluster.sh executed I have only one working node. Another 2 nodes return 
*{"errors":["Could not retrieve the redirect address of the current leader. Please try to refresh."]}* from web UI

and exception in flink-root-standalongsession-.log:

```
2018-08-07 18:55:22,081 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.files.StaticFileServerHandler  - Could not retrieve the redirect address.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing token not set: Ignoring message LocalFencedMessage(aec7a76447f8d44131605f5c10fb4fdc, LocalRpc
...
<------>at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
<------>at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing token not set: Ignoring message LocalFencedMessage(aec7a76447f8d44131605f5c10fb4fdc, LocalRpcInvocation(requestRestAddress(T
<------>at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:59)
```

Comment: The same exception I have seen with 1.5.1 version, but web UI works. Version 1.4.2 works well - no exceptions occured.